# NGINX SSL The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, ssl

Hi I have strange error message when I check my SSL certificate on various websites. Although Web browser says https perfectly fine can see lock and I've always go sectigo website, it gives me CSR code which I create in Centos to create cert at sectigo. I search but couldn't find much information last 2 days. my nginx partial code is

```
server {
        listen  443 default_server;

        server_name www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com;

    #### REAL SSL STARTS ####
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/STAR_xxxxxxxxx_com.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ### REAL SSL ENDS    ####
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
```

Error message I am receiving

The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Is there any other certificate other than these 2 ?

Comment: There probably is, and whoever you purchased the certificate from should have provided it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Its turned out to be I did wrong key installed interestingly no any browser give me error other than ssl checker websites. I found a website give me correct crt file I just had to replace this with the ssl-bundle VALA! website I used: whatsmychaincert.com